# how can I sum selected checkbox(s) row values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table in asp.net mvc . in this table I have a checkbox for every row . I want when I check a checkbox find wage value in that row and sum with other rows wages that checked .
I want to do this sum via Jquery or java script .

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
        <tr id="rowid">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk-@intCount" id="chk-@intCount" class="chkclass" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TechnicalNo)
            </td>
            <td class="sum" id="wagein">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Wage)
            </td>
            <td class="sum" id="time">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time)
            </td>
        </tr>
 }
```

this is my code in asp.net mvc . how can I sum checked values in wage and time now ?

EDIT :

My jQuery code :

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.chkclass').click(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.chkclass:checked').each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.wagein').text());    
        });
        $('#sum').html(sum);
    });​
    });
</script>
```

my html code :

```
<tr>
    <td>
         <input type="checkbox" name="chk-1" id="chk-1" class="chkclass" />
    </td>
    <td class="sum wagein">
        10
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk-2" id="chk-2" class="chkclass" />
    </td>
    <td class="sum wagein">
        10
    </td>
</tr>
```

any idea ?! what is the problem ?!

Comment: You arre on a *very* old version of jquery - thought about upgrading? Should be mostly backward compatible!

Comment: The combination of your markup shown here, and your jquery code works fine. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADE3a/ - only difference is im outputting the total to a new div with the id `total` placed below the table.

Comment: @Jamiec : I Upgrade it to 1.8.0 . your jsfiddle demo not works . but for Darin works .

Comment: You must stop saying "Doesnt work". How does it not work? Do you get an error? does the sum not show up? Anyhow it worked fine for me - what browser are you using?

Comment: @Jamiec : I'm using google chrome .

Comment: @Persian., so will you show your actual markup so that we can help you? Or not?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : of course . you need all my html code ? or table and jquery code ?

Comment: @Persian., I need all your HTML code. From `<html>` to `</html>`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : Okay . I uploaded it on site in txt file for you : http://novindesign.com/code.txt

Comment: @Persian., there's a `});?` in your HTML inside your script. This is invalid javascript on the line immediately after `$('#sum').html(sum);`. Remove this question mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by fixing your markup as it is highly broken. Remember that ids must be unique throughout your entire HTML document:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk-@intCount" id="chk-@intCount" class="chkclass" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TechnicalNo)
        </td>
        <td class="sum wagein">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Wage)
        </td>
        <td class="sum">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

then you could subscribe to the `.click()` event of the checkboxes and accumulate a sum for all wages:

```
$(function() {
    $('.chkclass').click(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.chkclass:checked').each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.wagein').text());
        });
        alert(sum);
    });
​});
```

And here's a live demo to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/pbkjr/

Comment: *It's not working*. It's as if you said nothing to me. Define *not working*. Because this works perfectly fine for me as you can see in this live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pbkjr/ *Not working* is a sentence commonly employed by users that do not know or care how a program works. Developers asking for help on the other hand must explain this in more details. Are they getting an error? Have you consulted your javascript debugging tool console? ...

Comment: Yes it works in your demo . but I don't know why it is not working for me . I Past your code in my page . but not works yet . what is the problem ?! :|

Comment: How on Earth am I supposed to know why your code is not working without showing your code? You probably made a mistake. I cannot know this as I cannot read your mind. Care to show the rendered HTML markup of your view?

Comment: I need to see the rendered HTML markup as seen by the browser, not your Razor code.

Comment: No, that's only a single table row. Please show your FULL HTML as seen by your browser. Right click in your browser => select View Page Source. Then select all, copy to clipboard and paste here so that I can see your actual code.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - OP has posted 2 rows not one, just badly laid out markup (and looks nothing like what his razor code looks like)

Comment: @Jamiec, this doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Persian., the 2 checkboxes you have shown have the same id: `id="chk-1"` => I already told you that ids must be **UNIQUE throughout your entire HTML**. So go fix your markup. I have strictly no idea what `@intCount` is (since you don't show your code) but it seems that you are not correctly incrementing it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Although you are 100% right about dupe id's it will have zero effect on the working of this code!

Comment: Alright, but you still haven't shown your markup. And I still cannot read your mind.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : Darin it works in firefox . but not in Chrome . what is the issue ?

Comment: @Persian., I already told you that I cannot answer this question without seeing your full HTML code. The jsfiddle I wrote works fine for me on IE, Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, starting with the markup you have shown, correctly wrapped with `<table></table>` tags, with a div below to show the total:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
         <input type="checkbox" name="chk-1" id="chk-1" class="chkclass" />
    </td>
    <td class="sum wagein">
        10
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk-2" id="chk-2" class="chkclass" />
    </td>
    <td class="sum wagein">
        10
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="total"></div>
```

The following jquery (which @Darin wrote) will sum all the checked rows when any checkbox is clicked:

```
$('.chkclass').click(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.chkclass:checked').each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.wagein').text());    
        });
        $('#total').html(sum);
    });
```

This is very close to Darin's original, except that I have changed the last line to output the total to the div with id `total`. This seems more likely than writing the sum to every row!

This can be seen in this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ADE3a/

Comment: don't you think that your answer resembles something? What's the point in posting the same answer twice?

Comment: Yes, yes I do. It is ***exactly*** the code the OP wrote, with 1 minor change. Sometime people just need confirmation that they're on the right track, and this might prompt the OP for where they have made a mistake. Beats droning on about them not posting their markup when they have!

Comment: No, not the code the OP wrote. The code **I wrote** that he copied in his question and you copied in your answer! If you look at the original question the OP posted, there's no single trace of javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt compare edit histories to minutae. My appologies, i'll update this question to correctly give you credit for the 5 lines of jquery.

Comment: @Jamiec : Your jsfiddle demo not works Jamic . but for Darin works .

Comment: @Persian. All I can say is you're either using a weird browser or have javascript switched off because I have tested that fiddle with 6 browsers and it works perfectly. When you check or uncheck a checkbox the total is updated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
        sum = 0;
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).closest('div').find('.payment').val());
        });
        $('#total').val(sum);
    });
});
```

Darin Dimitrov

Thanks a ton. I was having a issue where I wanted do addition of hidden fields for checked check boxes and pass the checkbox value(true or false) to the controller.

@Html.CheckBoxFor was creating a hidden field right next to it for each checkbox

I was using $(this).next().val() this was giging me NAN issue. since it was getting the value of the hidden field.

Thanks you to your post I was able to get the next div hidden field value

I did something like below

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  In addition to the answer you've provided, consider giving a summary as to why this solves the issue.